# How does z-index work with full screen?

Tags: css, html, iframe, z-index, fullscreen

Currently I'm having issues with Twitch's iframe stream video. When I select full screen, the z-index is no longer active. It is hidden under an iframe. Please guide everyone how to fix. Thanks for reading.
   https://codepen.io/pobby/pen/bKbNZo

```
<div id="twitch-embed">
        <div class="cr_display_logo">TEST</div></div>

<!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
<script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
width: 854,
height: 480,
channel: "tonyteo2018",
layout: "video",
autoplay: false
});

embed.addEventListener(Twitch.Embed.VIDEO_READY, () => {
var player = embed.getPlayer();
player.play();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me...but  i recommand to set 1 in z-index `z-index: 1;`

Comment: @KidsVN y Elaborate your question what exactly you want which div you want to above the iframe.

Comment: @לבנימלכה Can you help me fix the code on the codepen that works as intended?

Comment: @MerajKhan Sorry for my question, because I do not use English. I want the class cr_display_logo to be above the video when full screen

Comment: @KidsVN its working fine.